# JavaScript React setInterval WITHOUT fat-arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, setinterval, arrow-functions

I'm starting React and I saw I could set up a clock using a fat-arrow function inside my setInterval():

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { date: new Date() }
        this.timer = null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = window.setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ date: new Date() })
        }, 1000)
    }
```

But I did not manage to get the same result with a regular function (below). I think it's linked to the "this" keyword creating a new context inside a regular function? I have no idea how to fix this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        this.setState({ date: new Date() })
    }, 1000)
}
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly because a new `this` is created for a regular function (btw, don't confuse the context and `this`), rules for regular functions and `this` are:

- a new object in the case of a constructor
- undefined in functions call in strict mode
- the current object if the function is called as a method

Your case is the third, but the trick is that when using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, the callback function is called as a method, but in the global scope (`this`==`window`).

The classical way is to save `this` in a variable. Because the function can access the context it was created in, it will remember this variable:

```
var self = this;
this.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    self.setState({ date: new Date() })
}, 1000)
```

You can also use `bind`

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions automatically bind the context of the parent scope. But `regular function` doesn't do that as default. In order to change the context of the regular functions, you can use `bind` method as below example.

```
this.timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    this.setState({ date: new Date() })
}.bind(this), 1000)
```